# Use @CacheResult when the method has no argument

Tags: java, caching, ehcache, spring-cache, jcache

I have a method that returns the (rarely-changed) configuration of a system and want to cache it. The configuration is built from different pieces of data so I don't want to cache the individual pieces, but the `SystemConfiguration` object itself.

There is no argument to the method, how can I tell Ehcache to use a fixed key "configuration" (there's only one instance of the configuration)? Do I have to create a `CacheKeyGenerator` or is there a simpler method?

```
@CacheResult //how to specify the fixed key?
public SystemConfiguration getConfiguration() {
  return configuration; //this is a prebuilt object, as described
}
```

Comment: I created a CacheKeyGenerator in the meantime. A little bit extra code but it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring caching has a [default key generation algorithm](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html#cache-annotations-cacheable-default-key) that will cover the use case of methods with no arguments.

However, if you want a specific value for the key then you need to implement your own generator.

Comment: This is what I had to do; the default SimpleKey.EMPTY was not appropriate as I have several such cases besides just the SystemConfiguration object.